# What can cause devtools::document() and devtools::lint() to stop recognizing imports?

Tags: r, devtools

I was modifying my R package and suddenly `document()` stopped recognizing the functions I was getting using `@importFrom`. The only way I could use my package was to prefix package names (e.g. `stringr::str_detect`). Since I have a lot of these, this took a very long time. This started happening after I deleted my `NAMESPACE` file because I accidentally left an `@importFrom` blank. `devtools::document()` still appears to work fine for my other projects. I've noticed `lint()` is also seeing these fake problems.

I keep the package files in version control, but haven't seen any obvious reasons it would stop working. What kind of text error could cause this?

Some examples:

I have the following code block defining a utility function in my package:

```
#' Check if string ends with y.
#' @param x String.
#' @param y String Scalar.
#' @importFrom stringr str_sub str_length
str_ends_with <- function(x, y) {
  stopifnot(length(y) == 1)
  leny <- str_length(y)
  lenx <- str_length(x)
  ifelse(lenx < leny, FALSE,
         str_sub(x, start = lenx - leny + 1) == y)
}
```

Yet, `lint()` sees

```
R/util.R:69:11: warning: no visible global function definition for 'str_length'
  leny <- str_length(y)
          ^~~~~~~~~~
R/util.R:70:11: warning: no visible global function definition for 'str_length'
  lenx <- str_length(x)
          ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: what does `devtools::document()` output now?

Comment: It gives an error saying a function is not in scope. It seems to pick each function that lint finds and tells me about it one at a time.

Comment: Can you share your namespace? Not much to go with now. Prob try clean and rebuild then document again

Comment: Running `royxgen2::roxygenize()` on the package directory fixed the issue.  After that, I could run `devtools::document()` as normal.

Comment: great! maybe you can post an answer to your qn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `roxygen2::roxygenize()` successfully created a new `NAMESPACE` file. Usually `devtools::document()` can usually do this, but apparently not in my case. However, `document()` works as expected afterwards.